# How does ansible's service module handle conflicts in service name?

Tags: ansible

From Ansible doc:

> Supported init systems include BSD init, OpenRC, SysV, Solaris SMF,
>   systemd, upstart.

In what order does Ansible try to run the service?  What if there's both a init.d script for service X and also an upstart script in /etc/init?

Comment: The source is available. Did you check it?

Comment: Have you looked at [the source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/system/service.py)? I'm pretty sure you know enough Python to answer your own question. :)

Comment: Just to point out that the source url has changed. The core modules are no longer a separate repo, but inside the Ansible main repo itself. The url you are looking for is [`ansible/lib/ansible/modules/system/service.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/system/service.py)

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [docs for ansible.builtin.service](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html):

> Parameter: `use`
>
> The service module actually uses system specific modules, normally
> through auto detection, this setting can force a specific module.

So the official answer is that Ansible decides internally what to
use.

More specifically:

> Normally it uses the value of the 'ansible_service_mgr' fact and falls
> back to the old 'service' module when none matching is found.

So, Ansible normally uses an Ansible fact, 'ansible_service_mgr', which tells it which init system to use. If that is not successful, the 'service' module is used, which has its own auto detection logic (see below).

---

The fact 'ansible_service_mgr' is determined in [facts/system/service_mgr.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.9/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/system/service_mgr.py), by checking various system properties, such as OS name and presence of certain files.

As for the fallback to the old 'service' module:
Looking at ist code( [modules/service.py on Github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/service.py) ), it seems that ansible performs the detection in two steps:

- detect the platform and possibly distribution it is running on (via [common/sys_info.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/common/sys_info.py), get_platform_subclass )
- delegate to a platform-specific subclass of class Service, such as LinuxService, FreeBsdService etc.

These platform-specific subclass will then try to detect the init system to use. The LinuxService for example will try the following init systems in order:

- systemd
- upstart
- OpenRC
- SysV init

However, it is probably wise not to rely on this, as it is not officially documented and may change.

Comment: This answer is somewhat misleading. That is the legacy module, which is rarely used; the actual thing called by a `service` task is the action plugin, https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/service.py  , which will generally call a specific module like `systemd` rather than the `service` module.

Comment: @flowerysong: That is true. However, the Q was explicitly about the "service module", it quoted from its docs ( ["Supported init systems include BSD init, OpenRC, SysV, Solaris SMF, systemd, upstart."](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/service_module.html) ), so my answer addresses that.

Comment: Also, I could not find any "official" information about the "service" module being legacy, it still seems fully supported according to the latest docs. Do you have any pointer about that?

Comment: The question asked about the module because the existence of action plugins is transparent to end users; they're called the same way as normal modules, and their documentation is in the module namespace (when there's no corresponding module, a stub is added that contains just the documentation). You can see the treatment of the module as a fallback after the normal autodetection at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/service.py#L59-L67 (note that the `ansible.legacy` namespace is not relevant, that's related to the collection split.)

Comment: Or to put it another way: the documentation you are looking at is for the action plugin. When the action plugin is unable to determine a more specific module to call, it calls the monolithic `service` module, and that is the point at which the logic covered in your answer kicks in. Since there are specific modules for `systemd`, `sysvinit`, `sysrc`, `runit`, `svc`, and probably others that I'm forgetting, the secondary detection logic in the monolithic module rarely matters and should not be the main focus of your answer.

Comment: @flowerysong: Thanks for the explanation. I realize I don't know Ansible internals well enough to explain this coherently. Feel free to edit my answer with your comments (or post an answer of your own).

Comment: I edited to explain the use of the 'ansible_service_mgr' fact.